# Layout height that will depend on device screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

How can I achieve this layout in the photo?

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S7cH.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S7cH.png

```
<RelativeLayout >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/redlayout"></LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/yellowlayout">
               <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/yellowchild1"></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/yellowchild2"></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/yellowchild3"></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/yellowchild4"></LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bluelayout"></LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

the **yellowchilds** layout height will depend on the **yellowlayout's** height.

Comment: Check out `android:layout_weithgt` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **layout_weight** property.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/redLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/yellowLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yellowChild1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yellowChild2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yellowChild3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/yellowChild4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/blueLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your red, yellow and blue layouts all have percentage screen heights,  I suggest you make your root layout as `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. There you can provide the `android:layout_weight` value to 1, 7 and 2 to red, yellow and blue layouts respectively. Within `yellowLayout`, just give each child a `android:layout_weight=1` value for that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using layout weight like this:

```
<LinearLayout vertical orientation>
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.1>    //red
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.175>  //yellow
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.175>  //yellow
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.175>  //yellow
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.175>  //yellow
    <LinearLayout layout_weight=0.2>    //blue
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/redlayout"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/yellowlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yellowchild1"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

           <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/yellowchild2"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yellowchild3"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yellowchild4"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

     </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bluelayout"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
```

That'll make it just like you requested, and will scale over different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code simply with out any changes you can get a perfect result what you want.....

```js
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
 <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/redlayout"
  android:background="#64759" 
  android:layout_wight="1";
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"

 ></LinearLayout>


         <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/yellowlayout"
  android:background="#ffff66" 
  android:layout_wight="1";
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  >
               <LinearLayout  
   android:id="@+id/yellowchild1"
   android:layout_wight="1";
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
  ></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  
   android:id="@+id/yellowchild2"
   android:layout_wight="1";
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
  ></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  
   android:id="@+id/yellowchild3"
   android:layout_wight="1";
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
  ></LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout  
   android:id="@+id/yellowchild4"
   android:layout_wight="1";
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
  ></LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/bluelayout"
  android:background="#800080"
  android:layout_wight="1";
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
 ></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```